# How to know whether my Android BroadcastReceiver is registered or not

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-sdcard, android-debug

I am using an BroadcastReceiver for action related to sd card events like mount / unmount.

Now the situation is my receiver is not working. My application only have an BroadcastReceiver no GUI, no Activity, no layout. So now I want to debug the code so I want a message to be printed when I am installing the application. So I am looking for an method like an `onCreate()` which Service and Activity have. I have read the official document of BroadcastReceiver here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

I was unable to find a method like that. So how can I know whether my android BroadcastReceiver is registered or not. Which method I have to use for getting the info whether my android BroadcastReceiver is registered or not. Is there any other way I can get the infothat mu receiver is registered and in tents are not working.

Here is my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.broadcastreceiversdcardinsertionremoval"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver
            android:name="SDCardStateChangeListener"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL" />

                <data android:scheme="file" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**and my  SDCardStateChangeListener.java which extends BroadcastReceiver**

```
package com.example.broadcastreceiversdcardinsertionremoval;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class SDCardStateChangeListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED)
                || action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED)
                || action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL)
                || action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT)) {

            Log.d("action", "Sd Card Event");

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you are not explicitly *registering* a receiver, you are *declaring* it in manifest, no need to register it again. All components whose manifest has a matching receiver filter, will be invoked (Package service keeps track of this stuff). In this case an object of class `SDCardStateChangeListener` will be instantiated and its  `onReceive()` method will be called.

You can just put a breakpoint or log message as first statement inside `onRecieve()` method to see if it is invoked or not.

Comment: Sir means you are trying to say that if I want my BroadcastReceiver to be dynamic then only we will register it.

Comment: @Nikhil you expilictly register by calling `registerReceiver()` method of your `Context`, you can unregister by `unregisterReceiver()` method of context. On the other hand, receivers declared in manifest are by default placed in system's registry when app is installed, these can't be unregistered on the go.

Comment: So sir is this true to say they are by default registered when declared in manifest.

Comment: @Nikhil yes, you can say it that way.

Comment: So there is no way I can get a proof for this.

Comment: Just put a breakpoint in onReceive, run your app under a debugger and eject the SD card. Your method will be called.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `android:exported="false"` you will never receive any broadcasts sent from outside your own app.